# Or condition in countifs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a table where I want to count entries of one property of data in another table, conditional on other properties (columns of data).

So I have a table of summaries as a grid of things like:

```
  =countifs(data type, "="&ColTags, data color, "="&ColTags, ...)
```

Where the ColTags are the header tags of the columns in the summary grid.

Now I want to add to this the ability to only summarize for only certain rows in the data not all (basically a filter). So I added to the *countifs* a criteria like:

```
   data city, "="&CityTag
```

where CityTag references a cell where the user can (optionally) enter a city to filter the summary entries by. I put "*" in that cell as the default, and it has the desired no effect (as expected), and if I put a city name there "Texas" then it properly shows the summary only for that city. Bravo.

It allows a simple way to have option a user filtering (selection) on the summary table for any city, or none.

This works find except for numeric entries in the data table.

For them, doing the same thing but entering a number in the selection cell (PriceTag) fails. That is, basically: "6=*" fails. But if I use an arithmetic comparison operator,

```
 data Price, ">="&PriceTag
```

it works. But just entering a "*" wildcard does not seem to work on numeric entries, it can only do actual value comparisons.

For example;

```
 countif( A1,"="&A2)

for:  A1   A2
      abc   *    ->  1
      abc   x    ->  0
      abc  abc   ->  1
```

but

```
   6    *    ->  0    ??
   6    5    ->  0
   6    6    ->  1
```

It seems that Excel is trying to auto-recognize and type numbers, and treat differently for wildcard comparisons, and thus there is no matching for "*" for numerics?

I tried to get around this by actually putting the condition (not just the value) in the selection Tag cell, like this:

```
countif( ... data Price, PriceTag  )
```

and then in the Tag cell actually putting:

```
"<100"    or such...
```

Again that works nicely, but I can't find any value to put there which is a No-op, i.e like a metacharacter "*" is for text. I could must use a huge number as a numeric default, but that fails for anything with a blank price field (which I have), making it different than a no-op default.

Trying "=*" as an operation doesn't work, as it seems to want to do a numeric comparison.

So given that, I wonder about some workaround for having "or" conditions for the *countifs* function, which now only accepts a series of AND conditions. To have some condition that says equivalently:

```
(PriceTag="*")||(data price, PriceTag)
```

One approach is to embed the *countifs* in an if statement;

```
   =if( PriceTag="*", Long-Countifs-without-Price, Long-countifs-with-price)
```

but this is notably messy, and since I want to allow two such numeric selections, even worse.

Any good Excel idioms for this? Or do I just have to convert to a sumProduct with (+,*) terms?
Trying to do that, the term:

```
   ...*(data city=CityTag)
```

(Where CityTag is a cell containing: *) evaluates to:

```
   { ...list of city names...} = "*"
```

which gives a result of:

```
 { False, False, ... }
```

I would have expected { True, True, ...} like I got with the sumifs result, so I still do not have a good solution.

Comment: For price (not-negative integer), use " >=0 " instead of " * ". "*" does not work for numeric data.

Comment: Thanks - as I noted above I had tried that, but it fails for blank price fields (which my data has). I may just have to go through and cleanup missing price data (convert into 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numbers and blank cells to be wildcarded by an asterisk, nest an IF() with constants *within* the COUNTIF/COUNTIFS and SUMming the return(s) like this,

`=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,IF(A2="*",{"","<1e99"},A2)))`

That only works as an array formula and must be finalized with Ctrl+Shift+Delete. If you are working with an OR of text values (e.g. city names) using direct comparison, it works as a standard formula.

`=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,{"abc","def",""}))`

This does not work by putting `={"abc","def",""}` into a cell and using the cell reference as the criteria parameter.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need the *=* signs
- For your default entry in PriceTag, use **<>x** instead, where **x** is any non-numeric character.

  =COUNTIFS(data type, ColTags, data color, ColTags, data Price, PriceTag)